# Determining sample size for a comparative study involving two unequal groups

Tags: sample, statistical-power

I will like to know the formula for calculating the minimum sample size required for a comparative study involving 2 groups with unequal size. Group 1 is 10 times greater than group 2.

Comment: What is the response variable? Do you expect dropouts?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 11.  Given that the size of the first group is 10 times the size of the second, 11 is the smallest possible sample size that includes at least one observation.  Now, you might say that this is ridiculous, but it turns out that a single observation is adequate for updating your prior beliefs, supposing that you are a [Bayesian](http://www.bayesian-inference.com/samplesize).

Given that you are almost certainly not a Bayesian, one might ask the following type of question:  What is the smallest sample size needed to reject the null hypothesis at least $x\%$ of the time if we assume that the true difference between groups is at least $y$ and we assume that the distribution of the response variable is $z$?

Specifying $x$, $y$, and $z$ is the first step towards getting the answer you seem to be seeking.

Answer (score 1):

The generic formula for sample size at a given power in a regression is

$$
N = \frac{2.84^2}{p(1-p)}\frac{\sigma^2}{MDE^2}
$$

N is your sample size, p is the proportion getting the treatment, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the residuals, and MDE=the minimum detectable effect that you are powered for.  2.84 comes from alpha confidence of 95% and 80% power.

The more explanatory factors you've got in your experiment the more $\sigma$ will shrink.  Knowing how much it will shrink is tricky.

At some point, analytical formulas collapse, and you're better off simply simulating your entire dataset, multiple times doing some sort of monte carlo, and fitting the desired model to each of the plausible datasets.  Your power is the proportion of times you get the result you want.  As with the analytical methods, you're only as good as your assumptions.

Source is from memory, roughly following [this](http://ideas.repec.org/h/eee/devchp/5-61.html).

This answer is a verbatim copy/paste of my answer to [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54693/power-for-experimental-design/54717#54717)