# How to modify post-hoc power analysis simulation to perform a-priori power analysis?

Tags: r, statistical-power

I am interested in doing a sample size calculation for exacerbation rates. I am drawing my data from a negative binomial distribution and my test statistic is based on a negative binomial glm. Currently, I have a code for a power calculation for a given sample size. How do I modify this code to calculate sample size?

The following are the input parameters for the sample size calculation:

- Alpha level = 0.04,
- target power = 90%,
- event rate for reference group (r0) = `mu0 <- 0.8/52*48`,
- Rate ratio (rr) under `ha = mu1/mu0` where `mu1 <- mu0*0.6`,
- average exposure time = 48 weeks,
- sample size allocation ratio = 1 (so each group has equal sample size; i.e., `n1 = n0`), and
- dispersion parameter (`k = 0.4`).

```
library(MASS)
n     <- 400        # sample size
alpha <- 0.04
int   <- 1000
k     <- 1/0.4      # shape
mu0   <- 0.8/52*50  # control exacerbation rate
mu1   <- mu0*0.4    # exacerbation rate for trt1
mu2   <- mu1        # exacerbation rate for trt2
t0    <- rep(0, n)
t1    <- rep(1, n)
ta1   <- c(t0, t1)
ta2   <- c(t0, t1)
c1    <- NULL
c2    <- c1
test1 <- c1
test2 <- c1

for (i in 1:int){
  pbo <- rnegbin(n, theta=k, mu=mu0)
  d1  <- rnegbin(n, theta=k, mu=mu1)
  d2  <- rnegbin(n, theta=k, mu=mu2)
  r1  <- c(pbo, d1)
  r2  <- c(pbo, d2)

  x1  <- cbind(ta1, r1)
  x2  <- cbind(ta2, r2)

  dt1 <- as.data.frame(x1)
  dt2 <- as.data.frame(x2)
  fm1 <- glm.nb(r1 ~ ta1, data = dt1)
  fm2 <- glm.nb(r2 ~ ta2, data = dt2)

  test1 <- c(test1, summary(fm1)$coef[2,4]) #$
  test2 <- c(test2, summary(fm2)$coef[2,4]) #$
  c1    <- c(c1,    summary(fm1)$coef[2,3]) #$
  c2    <- c(c2,    summary(fm2)$coef[2,3]) #$
}

#power
result <- (sum( (test1<alpha)&(test2<alpha) )/int) 
result
```

Comment: I wrote up a fairly comprehensive overview / guide to using simulations for power analyses here: [Simulation of logistic regression power analysis - designed experiments](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35994/7290), but I didn't do a very good job w/ this part. @GregSnow's [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36040/7290) does a better job.

Comment: Hi Gung,Thanks for your reply. I read the thread you mentioned and Greg's part too. I am not sure how I can modify my code to get the sample size. Could you explain this a bit more