# Monte Carlo for DOE Power Calculation When Performance is Unknown

Tags: logistic, simulation, statistical-power

I have been wanting to get away from using power calculation tools (JMP, Lenth) in favor of Monte Carlo techniques to determine the a-priori power to observe factor level effects in a DOE.  I am really new to this and have a few questions.  Lets start with what I have:

1. A binomial response which I plan to perform a logistic regression to
2. List of factors that I think are relevant
3. A model (Main Effects + interaction + quadratic terms)
4. An experimental design (Taken from JMP or the DoE.wrapper package)
5. A threshold requirement (0.6)
6. An effect size (ES = 0.1)

I would like to determine the power to observe an effect in the response for each one of the model terms.  I have read the excellent [response by user gung](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments) which I wanted to use to help tailor my own approach.  After reading, I had a few specific questions.

1. The example uses prior knowledge of the system performance (the rates) that I do not have.  How do I continue without this knowledge?
2. The solution does not factor in effect size in any way (at least as far as I can tell).  How do I factor in effect size to this process?
3. The power for each of the terms is coming from the significance of the model term to be non-zero.  Is this the same as the power to observe an effect size in the response?

For question 2, I would assume that you would just need to run the model assuming the null performance (p = 0.6) and then re-run the fit assuming the performance of Null + Effect Size (p = 0.6 + ES).  I know this last part might be a bit jumbled up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.