# Is there any conventional small, medium and large effect sizes for ordinal logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, statistical-power, ordered-logit

I was performing a power analysis of articles published in a journal of management using the `pwr` package in R. However, it seemed to be impossible to compute power for small, medium and large effect sizes for multiple ordinal logistic regression. I have tried using `G*power`, but it only seemed to be useful when we have simple logistic regression output. Thus, I have tried to simulate to calculate the power based on the answers by @GregSnow and @gung here: [Simulation of logistic regression power analysis - designed experiments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments). How can I get power for small, medium and large effect sizes in multiple ordinal logistic regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplified notions of effect size just get us into trouble, and there are no cutoffs that work universally.  I usually specify an odds ratio and distribution for a predictor for ordinal regression.  For the proportional odds case, power of a simple unadjusted 2-sample comparison can be computed using the R `Hmisc` package `popower` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful answer. I have solved my problem. Using G*power, the main point is to compute R². The answer resides in the correlation matrix: this matrix permits to calculate the R² among the X. To determine X distribution, the descriptive statistics of the article may be helpful. Hope this help people! Thank again!