# Power simulation for Poisson Regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, poisson-distribution, simulation, statistical-power

I am interested in a power analysis for a Poisson regression of the form:

$Y_{i,1} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}Y_{i,0}+\beta_{2}Z_{i}$

where...

$Y_{i,1} $=The count from the 'post period' for case $i$

$Y_{i,0} $=The count from the 'pre period' for case $i$

$Z_{i} $=An indicator (0 or 1) of treatment for case $i$

There are $n_{0}$ and $n_{1}$ samples from each the control and treatment cases respectively.

I am wondering how to best simulate for a power analysis? What I know:

- We need to declare a minimally important effect size in terms of a multiplier for the treatment, the $\beta_{2}$. Lets say this is a six percent increase on average so effect is log(1.06)
- I do have data without a treatment and ran the model above with the treatment indicator and have the parameter estimates $\beta_{0}$ = 5.083739 and $\beta_{1}$ = 0.002056
- Since I have the values of $Y_{i,0}$ from the time without a treatment, I could use `fitdist()` in R for example to estimate the parameters of this data in say a poisson

**Question: What uncertainty needs to be captured in a power analysis like this?**

Is it sufficient to do the following (repeated nsim times) or is this not capturing enough uncertainty by using the static values of $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$ ? If not how?

```
#loop this nsims times
n0<-30
n1<-30
B0<-5.083739
B1<-0.002056
effect<-1.06

#treatment indicator
treat<-c(rep(0,n0),rep(1,n1))

#sample of values for the "pre-period" based on prior data this is how the pre-period is distributed
Y0<-as.integer(rpois(n0+n1,505))

lin_pred<-B0+B1*Y0+log(effect)*treat
Y1<-as.integer(exp(lin_pred))

mod<-glm(Y1~Y0+treat,family=poisson)
#extract the p-value from here
summary(mod)
```

**ADD #1**

To Greg's questions, the data is paired in the sense that the same units (geographical units such as markets) are measured twice. $Y_{i,1}$ is the response variable after the intervention period (only some markets are treated of course) and $Y_{i,0}$ is the value before the intervention period....a "Pre-test" sometimes called.

This methodology comes from Google's Data Science team [here](http://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2016/06/estimating-causal-effects-using-geo.html)
and Andrew Gelman ([Here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/chap9.pdf))

a snippet of the former is:

[image]

a snippet of this later reference is:

[image]

**ADD #2**

Here is another take at this which I believe is closer to Greg's point about $Y_{1}$ not having any randomness except as inherited from $Y_{0}$

```
poisson.power.1cov<-function(alpha=0.05,nsims=NULL,n0=NULL,n1=NULL, covariate=NULL, B0=NULL, B1=NULL, possible.effects=NULL )
{
  #hold power estimates for each effect
  powers <- rep(NA, length(possible.effects)) 

  #treatment indicator
  treat<-c(rep(0,n0),rep(1,n1))

  for (i in 1: length(possible.effects)) #loop over effects sizes
  {
      hold_power<-c()

      for (j in 1:nsims)
      {
        #linear predictor using assumed B0, B1 and the simulated covariate Y0
        lin_pred<-B0+B1*Y0+log(possible.effects[i])*treat 

        #exponentiate
        mu<-exp(lin_pred)

        #simulate Y1 based on mu (so here we are creating n0+n1 Y1 values, each of which has a different mu)
        Y1<-rpois(n=length(mu),lambda = mu)

        #fit model
        mod<-glm(as.integer(Y1)~as.integer(Y0)+treat,family=poisson)

        #extract p-value
        sum_mod <-summary(mod)
        hold_power<-rbind(hold_power,sum_mod$coefficients[3,4])

      } #loop sims
    powers[i]<-mean(hold_power < alpha)

    } #loop effects

  return(powers)

}

#effects of interest
effects<-seq(from=1.01, to=1.20, by=0.01)
#determined from aprior data
Y0<-as.integer(rpois(30,505))
#run power analysis with fixed B0 and B1
powers<-poisson.power.1cov(alpha = 0.05,n0 = 15,n1 = 15,nsims = 1000,covariate = Y0, B0 = 5.083739, B1 = 0.002056, possible.effects = effects)

#plot
plot(effects,powers)
lines(effects,rep(0.8,length(effects)))
```

Which yields:

[image]

**ADD #3** Adds in simulation of Y0 at each sim, versus a static set

```
poisson.power.1cov<-function(alpha=0.05,nsims=NULL,n0=NULL,n1=NULL, covariate_mu=NULL, B0=NULL, B1=NULL, possible.effects=NULL )
{
  #hold power estimates for each effect
  powers <- rep(NA, length(possible.effects)) 

  #treatment indicator
  treat<-c(rep(0,n0),rep(1,n1))

  for (i in 1: length(possible.effects)) #loop over effects sizes
  {
      hold_power<-c()

      for (j in 1:nsims)
      {

        #simulate Y0
        Y0<-rpois((n0+n1),lambda = covariate_mu)
        #linear predictor using assumed B0, B1 and the simulated covariate Y0
        lin_pred<-B0+B1*Y0+log(possible.effects[i])*treat 

        #exponentiate
        mu<-exp(lin_pred)

        #simulate Y1 based on mu (so here we are creating n0+n1 Y1 values, each of which has a different mu)
        Y1<-rpois(n=length(mu),lambda = mu)

        #fit model
        mod<-glm(as.integer(Y1)~as.integer(Y0)+treat,family=poisson)

        #extract p-value
        sum_mod <-summary(mod)
        hold_power<-rbind(hold_power,sum_mod$coefficients[3,4])

      } #loop sims
    powers[i]<-mean(hold_power < alpha)

    } #loop effects

  return(powers)

}

#effects of interest
effects<-seq(from=1.01, to=1.20, by=0.01)
#determined from aprior data
covariate_mu <-505
#run power analysis with fixed B0 and B1
powers<-poisson.power.1cov(alpha = 0.05,n0 = 15,n1 = 15,nsims = 1000,covariate_mu =covariate_mu , B0 = 5.083739, B1 = 0.002056, possible.effects = effects)

#plot
plot(effects,powers)
lines(effects,rep(0.8,length(effects)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $Y1$ variable does not have any randomness to it other than what it inherits from $Y0$.

Is this meant to be paired data? i.e. 2 measurements on each subject, one in each time period or with each treatment? If so, then you should probably be analyzing using a glmm model (lme4 package) instead of a glm model.

Also it is not completely clear what the relationship/difference is between your time periods and your treatment.

In general I would create the `lin_pred` variable based on your estimated coefficients, then generate $Y0$ and $Y1$ from a Poisson distribution with mean equal to `exp(lin_pred)`.

Comment: Greg, I added "Add #1" to the question, is this more clear?

Comment: Does that change your recommendation? I am not sure I completely follow simulating both from exp(lin_pred) as it is based off of Y0.

Comment: I just added another run ("Add #2") of the approach - does this look better where I am simulating Y1 from exp(lin_pred) which was created from simulating Y0 and using the fixed B0 and B1?

Comment: @B_Miner, yes that is much more along the lines that I was thinking.  Though you may want to use `log(Y0)` for the `lin_pred`.  And it is better to pre-specify the size of `hold_power` rather than expanding using `rbind`.

Comment: As always thanks Greg! I am very much looking forward to any articles you write on the topic.

Comment: Just to confirm - the recommendation for log(Y0) is not to do with power considerations per say, but as probably a better fit for the model to take the log of the covariate?

Comment: @B_Miner, correct.  It is just because the usual link for the Poisson is the log.

Comment: I added one last version, I should have been simulating Y0 each simulation, versus passing in a fixed vector to use.

Comment: @B_Miner, it is looking good.  I would still suggest using `log(Y0)` so that they are more on the same scale.

Comment: I also ended up seeing that the simulation of the $Y_{0}$ using rpois was not supplying a good match to the empirical data. So I ended up using an inverse from a cdf.



e <- ecdf(past_data$pre_period)
Y0<-as.integer(quantile(e,runif(n0+n1)))

Comment: @B_Miner, sampling from the inverse ecdf is the same as sampling with replacement from the data used to create the ecdf, a bootstrap sample.  A reasonable approach (though the bootstrap sample is probably a little simpler).

Comment: I wonder if we are talking about 2 different things. The procress I am using creates elements NOT in the original data. Here is the process: pre_data<-c(7893, 6256, 3240, 3085, 3033, 2973, 2820, 2347, 2341, 2285, 2121, 2093, 1929, 1700, 1640, 1402, 1135,
            986,  595,  576,  557,  536,  499,  499,  472,  452,423,  304,  248,  220,  193,  191,  184,  148,  140,  101)
pre_data
e <- ecdf(pre_data)

Y0<-as.integer(quantile(e,runif(30)))
Y0

Comment: @B_Miner, your method is still a variant on the bootstrap, just not the usual sample with replacement version (your ecdf is not the traditional step shaped, but linear between the points).  Still a good approach.