# Multiple regression: How to calculate required sample sizes for individual predictors (preferably in R)?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, statistical-power

I'm doing a multiple regression analysis in R on an epidemiological data set with five predictor variables as follows:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
```

With my data (n = 240), I get highly significant p values (< 10^8) for `x1`, and p values in the range of 0.09 to 0.35 for the remaining four variables.

Power analysis using `pwr.f2.test()` in the `pwr` library in R shows that the power is near 1. (Incidentally, allowing factor interactions does not significantly improve the fit. The residuals are Gaussian.)

I need to determine whether we should collect more data and, if so -- this is the crux of the problem -- what the sample size should be in order to provide a power of >=0.90 for *each* individual predictor variable. For instance, p value for `x2` is 0.091. How much additional data do we need to collect to avoid a Type II erorr (at >=0.90 level) for this variable? Or, more generally, how to determine these requisite individual sample sizes (preferably in R)?

I'm considering the following two approaches:

1. Use simple linear regression: Model each of remaining variables individually (e.g., `y ~ xi`, where `xi` refers to x2, x3, x4 or x5 by itself), and use the results as inputs to `pwr.f2.test()`.
2. Work off the above multiple regression model: Calculate the partial regression values corresponding to each individual variable from the multiple regression model, and use them as inputs to `pwr.f2.test()`.

Is either of these approaches statistically sound or is there a better way for doing this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Closely related: [Simulation of logistic regression power analysis - designed experiments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35940/7290).

Comment: Because legitimate p-values are *always* between 0 and 1, by "very high p values (< 10^8)" what do you mean??  Since power (and Type II errors) are functions of effect size, what do you mean by "power is near 1"??