# Calculate sample size for linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, sample-size, gpower

I have a total of 9 independent variables (IVs) and 1 dependent variable (DV). 2 of the IVs are binary and the other IVs are continuous ranging from 0 to 5. The DV is continuous ranging from 0 to 5000.

My hypotheses look like the following:

1. IV *X1* is positively associated with the DV *Y*
2. IV *X2* predicts DV *Y* indirectly through IV *X3*

I have multiple hypotheses of the first version (1.). The mediator model (2.) is the main hypothesis of my study. I want to use a hierarchical regression to test for my hypotheses.

How can I calculate the needed sample size (using G-Power)?

In G-Power: Do I use 'Linear multiple regression: Fixed model, R2 increase' to calculate the sample size? If yes, what effect size should I use to calculate the sample size?

Comment: Canned software isn't going to be good for something like this.  I would simulate.

Comment: How would you simulate? What do I have to do? Sorry for the question, I am a beginner.

Comment: If you're a beginner, you should probably work with a statistical consultant. You can get a sense of how it works by reading the duplicate.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for answer. But I don't understand how that helps me to determine the needed sample size for my regression :/

Comment: My apologies, @Jensxy. Simulation is often used for power analyses. The basic procedure is to simulate the data generating processes you believe exist at a given N, & determine the proportion of times it yields significance. Then you can search over Ns. There is an example in my answer here: [Simulation of logistic regression power analysis - designed experiments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35994/7290). As I say, this is something that's unlikely to be very doable for a beginner; you'd be better off working with a statistical consultant.

Comment: Hmm okay, thank you. I thought there would be an easy way.